# Read HttpResponseMessage with WebBrowser object returned from Web API method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a requirement wherein I need to post data to web api method from webbrowser object in a class library. I am able to post data and process the same. But Web API returns HttpResponseMessage which I need to read with WebBrowser object.

Example:

Post Data:

```
 this.Navigate(url, "", postData, additionalHeaders);
```

Web API Returns:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, "<GUID>");
```

Now, I want to get the status and read the GUID from WebBrowser object.
(Like we read DocumentText in OnDocumentCompleted event).

Or do I need to make changes in Web API method to read GUID?

Answer (score 0):

Whoa !!! I just need to add:

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
```